# Presenting a Hashmap on a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I am parsing some JSON data a truck key (id) and a name (value). I put it in a HashMap and I want to display **only** the *Value* in the `ListView`.

However I keep getting this error

> HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry

on this line: `return (Map.Entry) mArrayList.get(position);` in my TruckAdapter.

***Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?***

Here is the meat of the parsing the JSON, adding it to the ArrayList and then instantiating the listview adapter.

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>>  listTrucks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayRecordSet.length(); i++) {
        record = arrayRecordSet.getJSONObject(i);
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("MYKEY", record.getString("SOME TRUCK KEY"));
        map.put("MYVALUE", record.getString("SOME TRUCK VALUE"));

    listTrucks.add(map);
    }

    TruckAdapter truckAdapter = new TruckAdapter(listTrucks);
    lv.setAdapter(truckAdapter);
```

**My Adapter Class**

```
public class TruckAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final ArrayList mArrayList;

        public TruckAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> map){
            mArrayList = map;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
            return (Map.Entry) mArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View result;

            if (convertView == null) {
                result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            } else {
                result = convertView;
            }

            Map.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);

            ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(item.getValue());


            return result;
        }
    }
```

JSON

```
[{"TRKlTruckKey":"1","TRKch10TruckNumber":"Ford"},{"TRKlTruckKey":"2","TRKch10TruckNumber":"Jeep"} ......
```

Comment: i guess it just hashmap not arraylist of hashmap , can you show me your json

Comment: Show JSON response

Comment: I updated the question to add JSON

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, but you are trying to get a `Map.Entry<String, String>` from `getItem` method. Your list should be `ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>`, and fix the loading method:

```
Map.Entry<String, String> map;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRecordSet.length(); i++) {
    record = arrayRecordSet.getJSONObject(i);
    map = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(record.getString("SOME TRUCK KEY"), record.getString("SOME TRUCK VALUE"));
    listTrucks.add(map);
}
```

But, it could be much easy to create a POJO of Truck:

**Truck Class**

```
public class Truck {
    private String TRKlTruckKey; //+getters/+setters
    private String TRKch10TruckNumber; //+getters/+setters

    public Truck(String TRKlTruckKey, String TRKch10TruckNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Loading Method**

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRecordSet.length(); i++) {
    record = arrayRecordSet.getJSONObject(i);
    listTrucks.add(new Truck(record.getString("SOME TRUCK KEY", record.getString("SOME TRUCK VALUE")));
}
```

**Retriving Method**

```
@Override
public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    Truck truck = listTrucks.get(position);
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(truck.getTRKlTruckKey, truck.getTRKch10TruckNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class named `Truck`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRecordSet.length(); i++) {
    record = arrayRecordSet.getJSONObject(i);
    Truck truck = new Truck();
    truck.setKey(record.getString("TRKlTruckKey"));
    truck.setNumber(record.getString("TRKch10TruckNumber"));

    listTrucks.add(truck);
}
```

Then your Adapter's constructor:

```
public TruckAdapter(ArrayList<Truck> trucks){
    mArrayList = trucks;
}
```

And your getItem() method:

```
@Override
public Truck getItem(int position) {
    return mArrayList.get(position);
}
```